# Como receber um vetor, cujos valores são separados por espaços

Tags: python

Estou começando em python e uso um site que possui diversos problemas para resolução, nele os vetores e as matrizes são passado com os valores separados por um espaço e não virgula. Por exemplo:v = 1 2 3 43.

Sei que posso receber esse valor no input e deixar como string, a questão é como transforma essa string num vetor. Gostaria de saber se existe alguma função que consiga converter, pois se eu for "tratar" essa entrada eu perco a eficiência.

Comment: só fazer teste=v.split() não resolve ? vai converter uma string separada por espaço em uma lista...

Comment: tente usar ```map``` ou uma ```list comprehension```.

Comment: Vai depender de uma coisa. Sempre, cada valor vai ser único? Ou poderão existir chaves, tipo, com nome composto?

por exemplo: v = carlos silva 32 anos outro valor

Comment: Qual é sua entrada verdadeira? `v = 1 2 3 43` ou somente `1 2 3 43`? Se for o segundo caso, o comentário do @ederwander resolve (a propósito, poste isso como resposta). Caso contrário, você pode primeiro separar a chave do valor usando `x = entrada.split('=')` e depois separar cada valor individual usando `x[1].split()`.

Comment: mgibsonbr recebo 1 2 3 45 65, o comentário do @ederwander foi muito útil, e eu consigo chegar numa lista, só que a lista é composta por strings. ['1','2','3','43'], há uma maneira de transformar essa lista de strings em uma lista com números usando alguma função? Só consigo imaginar tento de converter um a um.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se é isso que deseja, para receber uma string com número e depois convertê-los, use o seguinte código:

```
>>> s = "1 2 3 56 88"
>>> map(int, s.split())
[1, 2, 3, 56, 88]
```

Explicando: `s.split()` transforma uma string em um vetor, utilizando o parâmetro como delimitador. O valor padrão do delimitador (que está oculto) é espaço.

Depois disso, ele é passado como entrada para a função `map`. Ela simplesmente executa uma função para cada elemento da lista. No caso, ele vai passar para a função `int`, que converte uma string para inteiro.

Note que ele vai gerar uma exceção `ValueError` caso não converta com sucesso.

Answer (score 1):

Bom vamos lá

Existe a possibilidade de você instalar o módulo numpy ?

O numpy é altamente recomendado quando você começa a trabalhar com vetores e matriz, ele realmente quebra um galho gigante.

Seu problema seria solucionado assim:

```
import numpy as np

v = "1 2 3 43"
teste=v.split() 
vetor = np.asarray(teste)
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é isso que você deseja, mas espero que ajude:
**a=map(int,input().split())**
Nesse caso o vetor **a** recebe uma lista de **ints** separados por espaço, virgula, barra, etc.